# sparksql not reading multidelimter csv file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read multidelimter (|,||) csv file by using pyspark sql, am not able read any data from dataframe its giving 0 records

sample data of csv file

```
Newyork|234567|company Ltd||PIN
```

---

```
df = spark.read.option.("sep","|").option("header","true").load(csv)
```

I need to read the data, is there any other way to handle this ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```scala
spark.read
      .option("sep", "|")
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv(spark.read.text("<path>").as(Encoders.STRING).map(_.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "|")))
```